# Web Disk Persistence Firebase Updates?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Question for the Firebase team...

Are there any new timeline updates for adding offline disk persistence to the web-based Firebase platform? I understand it's significantly harder to implement than it was with Android/iOS firebase, just haven't seen any updates on this topic for a bit and wanted to see if there was any new info.

Big thanks for such a great platform - I've been playing with Firebase 3.x a lot lately with great results.

-Brent

Comment: Nothing new to announce. We are aware that it's a highly desired feature, though. We'll definitely make some noise if and when we have more specifics. :)

Comment: Much appreciated, Michael!